# How do I write a json field to retrieve this?

Tags: android, json, android-json

I am currently using json for my code to retrieve an array of boolean values. However, i am adding a subfield to achieve another array within, but I am not good with json and kind of stuck how to go about it.
Here's my code so far:

field values :

```
 public enum Field {



       /**
         * Runtime Config Fields
         **/
        FIELD_CAN_CHANGE_PASSWORD("canChangePassword", true, canUpdate),
        FIELD_MAX_AUTO_DOWNLOAD_SIZE("maxAutoDownloadSize", 5000000L),
        FIELD_ALWAYS_REAUTHENTICATE("alwaysReauthenticate", false, canUpdate),
        FIELD_CAN_START_CALL("canStartCall", false),
        FIELD_ROOMS_ENABLED("roomsEnabled", !Core.isMessenger()),
        FIELD_CAN_CREATE_ROOM("canCreateRoom", !Core.isMessenger(), canUpdate),
        FIELD_MAX_ENVELOPE_TTL("maxTTL", Core.isMessenger() ? 518400L : 31536000L, canUpdate),
        FIELD_MAX_BURN_ON_READ_TTL("maxBOR", 0L, canUpdate),
        FIELD_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE("maxUploadSize", -1L, true),
        FIELD_FRIEND_FINDER("friendFinder", !Core.isEnterprise(), canUpdate),
        FIELD_ONLY_SHOW_IN_NETWORK_CONTACTS("onlyShowInNetwork", false),
        FIELD_CAN_ADD_CONTACT("canAddContact", true, canUpdate),
        FIELD_FORCE_DEVICE_LOCKOUT("forceDeviceLockout", 5L, canUpdate),
        FIELD_VERIFICATION_MODE("verificationMode", VerificationMode.OPTIONAL.getValue(), true),
        FIELD_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_PREVIEW("enableNotificationPreview", true, true),
        FIELD_DIRECTORY_ENABLED("directoryEnabled", true, true);

        public String fieldName;
        public Object defaultValue;
        public boolean updateFromServer;

        Field(String key, Object defaultValue) {
            this(key, defaultValue, true);
        }

        Field(String key, Object defaultValue, boolean updateFromServer) {
            this.fieldName = key;
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
            this.updateFromServer = updateFromServer;
        }
    }
```

putting values in field:

```
 private void putValueForField(JSONObject configuration, Field field) {
        try {
            if (configuration.isNull(field.fieldName)) {
                Object value = field.defaultValue;
                if (value instanceof long[]) {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    for (long obj : (long[]) field.defaultValue) {
                        array.put(obj);
                    }
                    value = array;
                }
                runtimeConfiguration.put(field.fieldName, value);
            } else {
                runtimeConfiguration.put(field.fieldName, configuration.get(field.fieldName));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
```

getting values :

```
 private Object getValueForField(Field field) {
        if (runtimeConfiguration.has(field.fieldName) && field.updateFromServer) {
            try {
                Object value = runtimeConfiguration.get(field.fieldName);
                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray values = (JSONArray) value;
                    if (values.get(0) instanceof Number) {
                        long[] retVals = new long[values.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                            retVals[i] = ((Number) values.get(i)).longValue();
                        }
                        return retVals;
                    }
                } else if (value instanceof Number) {
                    return ((Number) value).longValue();
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return field.defaultValue;
    }
```

one of the methods using the fields above:

```
 public boolean canChangePassword() {
        return (boolean) getValueForField(Field.FIELD_CAN_CHANGE_PASSWORD);
    }
```

My new json is :

> `{"enableNotificationPreview":true,"destructOnRead":[30,60,300],"alwaysReauthenticate":false,"forceDeviceLockout":0,"permmod":1516894585,"maxBOR":0,"roomsEnabled":true,"directoryEnabled":true,"canStartCall":true,"canAddContact":true,"legacyDownload":false,"verificationMode":1,"restrictedAdmin":false,"canChangePassword":true,"friendFinder":true,"NEWVALUE":{"canStartNewValue1":true,"canStartroupValue":true,"canVideoCall":true,"canStartRoomValue":true,"canAddtoValue":true,"canStartValueshare":true},"canCreateRoom":true,"maxTTL":2592000,"onlyShowInNetwork":false,"maxUploadSize":null,"availableEnvelopeTTL":[0,600,3600,86400,604800,2592000],"maxAutoDownloadSize":7340032}`

where I am plugging in :

> "NEWVALUE":{"canStartNewValue1":true,"canStartroupValue":true,"canVideoCall":true,"canStartRoomValue":true,"canAddtoValue":true,"canStartValueshare":true}

Not sure how to update my putValueForField to reflect this new json and the corresponding fields. Any idea?

Comment: If you just want to `retrieve nested JSON object` from  json object, you could simply do it by `JSONObject newvlaue = parentObject.get(NEWVALUE);`, assuming this parentObject is the parent JSON object which contains `newvalue` object

Comment: Also I noticed you posted similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460388/how-do-i-modify-my-function-to-retrieve-json-objects-to-a-nested-json, which I suppose asking for same answers or is there any difference ?

Comment: @warl0ck there isn't any difference between these 2 but since this one was TLDR , I posted a shorter version expecting people to respond, but this one gives a more detailed outlook of my question. Once any of these is answered, I'll close the other. I am pretty weak at JSON, can you modify my code and explain it, I tried a couple of things but didn't work, I'll really appreciate it! thanks!

Comment: sure, its just before posting it I wanted to clear it out that what I posted is exactly what you were asking. I'll post the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you are not good with json, why you don't use library for manipulate json object like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) ? This kind of library serialize and deserialize your object in json from your class model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check and retrieve `JSONObject` from the json object you can modify your method to check for `instance of JSONObject` and assign value to it.

```
 private void putValueForField(JSONObject configuration, Field field) {
        try {
            if (configuration.isNull(field.fieldName)) {
                Object value = field.defaultValue;
                if (value instanceof long[]) {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    for (long obj : (long[]) field.defaultValue) {
                        array.put(obj);
                    }
                    value = array;
                }
                // this is how you check if fieldName is of type jsonobject
                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject valueObject = configuration.getJSONObject(field.fieldName);
                    value = valueObject;
                }
                runtimeConfiguration.put(field.fieldName, value);
            } else {
                runtimeConfiguration.put(field.fieldName, configuration.get(field.fieldName));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
```

Form what I can understand you are just getting the values from JSON and saving it in field in that case:

I think in this method ultimately you are just storing all values as `object` only so while retrieving you have to do all this check again.

If you are getting the response from server with fixed Object fields and object values you should be creating a class from that configuration where you will know what exactly it will return. That would really make life easier.

Or maybe if you just need the configuration to get/update or put values you can maintain it in json object itself [Android JSON doc reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

For example lets say you have this jsonobject itself, I have added the working example below, hope this helps.

```
import org.json.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String jsn = "{\"enableNotificationPreview\":true,\"destructOnRead\":[30,60,300],\"" +
                "alwaysReauthenticate\":false,\"forceDeviceLockout\":0,\"NEWVALUE\":{\"canStartNewValue1\":true," +
                "\"canStartroupValue\":true,\"canVideoCall\":true,\"canStartRoomValue\":true},\"canCreateRoom\":true," +
                "\"maxTTL\":2592000,\"onlyShowInNetwork\":false,\"maxUploadSize\":null,\"availableEnvelopeTTL\"" +
                ":[0,600,3600,86400,604800,2592000],\"maxAutoDownloadSize\":7340032}";

        JSONObject jsnObj = new JSONObject(jsn);
        Object enableNotificationPreview = jsnObj.get("enableNotificationPreview");
        // or if you know it will be boolean
        boolean enableNotificationPreviewBool = jsnObj.getBoolean("enableNotificationPreview");
        System.out.println(enableNotificationPreview);
//        output : true
        System.out.println(enableNotificationPreviewBool);
//        output : true

        JSONObject NEWVALUEObj = jsnObj.getJSONObject("NEWVALUE");
//        now again you can extract values from it
        boolean canStartNewValue1 = NEWVALUEObj.getBoolean("canStartNewValue1");
        System.out.println(canStartNewValue1);
        NEWVALUEObj.put("canStartNewValue1", false);
        System.out.println(NEWVALUEObj.toString());
        jsnObj.put("forceDeviceLockout", 23456);
//        now canStartNewValue1 value is changed to false in the object
//        and forceDeviceLockout is also 23456
        System.out.println(jsnObj.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! I will try this out. Currently I am getting fixed objects with different boolean values from different servers. However, can I store the values in the json objects alongside the field params and it will just work or do i need to subclass field names aswell? example: FIELD_CAN_CHANGE_PASSWORD ,can i create another field for FIELD_CAN_SART_NEW_VALUE1 ,FIELD_GROUP_VALUE1 etc for objects within the json object in the same category or do i need to declare it differently? or subclass them?

Comment: Actually if you can store all configuration in json format that would be really easy, and If you need to update the values you can do that very easily. I have updated the answer also with reference.

Comment: thanks for the update! Is there an example you can point to with respect to my code ?would be helpful to do tat in accordance to an example

Comment: can you help out with the get function and the fields values aswell?

Comment: Yes sure, I'll update the answer with an example also