# How do I modify my function to retrieve json objects to a nested json?

Tags: android, android-json, jsonschema2pojo

Here's the json I currently use in my code :

```
{"forceDeviceLockout":0,"canStartValue":true,"destructOnRead":[30,60,300]}
```

I use the following function to get the json values:

```
private Object getValueForField(Field field) {
        if (runtimeConfiguration.has(field.fieldName) && field.updateFromServer) {
            try {
                Object value = runtimeConfiguration.get(field.fieldName);
                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray values = (JSONArray) value;
                    if (values.get(0) instanceof Number) {
                        long[] retVals = new long[values.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                            retVals[i] = ((Number) values.get(i)).longValue();
                        }
                        return retVals;
                    }
                } else if (value instanceof Number) {
                    return ((Number) value).longValue();
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return field.defaultValue;
    }
```

Now, I have a new nested json as follows:

> {"forceDeviceLockout":0,"canStartValue":true,"destructOnRead":[30,60,300],"NEWVALUE":{"canStartNewValue1":true,"canStartroupValue":true}

In the new json I am adding the nested json object : NEWVALUE which has 2 objects within itself.

I am a little weak at json so unsure how to go about modifying my code to retrieve the above individual values. Any ideas?

Comment: The JSON you have posted is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why are you making it so complicated! but see this code I wrote for you. it might give you an idea:

```
public void printFieldsValues(Object object){
    try{
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getFields();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        for(Field field : fields){
            jsonObject.put(field.getName(), field.get(object));
        }

        JSONObject newValue = new JSONObject("{\"canStartNewValue1\":true,"
                                             + "\"canStartroupValue\":true}");

        jsonObject.put("NEWVALUE", newValue);

        printJson(jsonObject);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void printJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException{
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    String           key;
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        key = keys.next();
        try{
            printJson(new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString(key)));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("TAG", "key = " + key);
            Log.d("TAG", "value = " + jsonObject.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and in your main Object you can call it like this:

```
printFieldsValues(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If those json keys are predefined we can access them like this

```
   public class SampleModel {

        public int forceDeviceLockout;
        public boolean canStartValue;
        public int[] destructOnRead;
        public NestedModel NEWVALUE; 
}



  public class NestedModel {
    public boolean canStartNewValue1;
    public boolean canStartroupValue;
}



  Gson gson = new Gson();
  SampleModel sampleModel = gson.fromJson("{\"forceDeviceLockout\":0,\"canStartValue\":true,\"destructOnRead\":[30,60,300],\"NEWVALUE\":{\"canStartNewValue1\":true,\"canStartroupValue\":true}}",SampleModel.class);
  Log.d("canStartNewValue : " ,sampleModel.canStartNewValue)
  Log.d("canStartNewValue1 : " , sampleModel.NEWVALUE.canStartNewValue1);
```

Note : Need to add dependency `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`

Comment: is it possible without using gson and just modifying my code? To give you an indepth idea of my code, here's the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447684/how-do-i-write-a-json-field-to-retrieve-this

Comment: @MarissaNicholas It's recommended to you GSON or any other alternative libraries for converting JSON to POJO and back again.
They help you tackle the boilerplate code which you wrote above

Comment: @AkshayChordiya Is there any easier way to do that without referring to 2 classes, like with enum fields? Do I need to nest out my sub json values aswell?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas Ideally we make the POJO classes exactly same to how JSON is coming, that is in your case your JSON is nested, in that case you'll need to 2 POJOs to represent the JSON.
I don't think Enums work

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify your current code to parse the json received you could just add
 `if(value instance of JSONObject){
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) value;
  return jsonObject; 
}`